# unable to understand recursive pattern and its function call

Tags: javascript, recursion

Recently i started to learn recursion in JavaScript.

i never called defined function in its own function.
what is this called?

i'm unable to understand how this recur(n - 1) working.

i tried to check how it working in chrome debugger, but there is no output too.

**`How here recur(n - 1) working?`**

```
function recur(n) {
 if(n === 1) return 1

 return n * recur(n - 1);
 // How here recur(n - 1) working?
 // 5 * 5 - 1 = 24
 // 4 * 4 - 1 = 15

}

recur(5);
```

Comment: _"what is this called?"_ - Recursion

Comment: The main thing to understand is that it isn't `5 * 5 - 1 = 24` but `5 * (4 * (3 * (2 * (1)))) = 120`

Comment: _"but there is no output too"_ - There's nothing in your example that would output anything -> Add some `console.log()`s or use the debugger to step through the script (add breakpoints)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So when you do return n * recur(n - 1), the first thing that is calculated is recur(n - 1).
What happens is the following

```
recur(5) = 5 * recur(5 - 1)
recur(4) = 4 * recur(4 - 1)
recur(3) = 3 * recur(3 - 1)
recur(2) = 2 * recur(2 - 1)
recur(1) = 1 => the bottom of the recursion. Now it starts to go back:
recur(2) = 2 * recur(1) = 2
recur(3) = 3 * recur(2) = 3 * 2 = 6
recur(4) = 4 * recur(3) = 4 * 6 = 24
recur(5) = 5 * recur(4) = 5 * 24 = 120
```

Basically, until a function of recur(n - 1) returns something concrete, like the bottom of the recursion in your case 1, the method calls recur once again, and again and so on. After you go to the bottom, then the functions start to resolve in the reverse order.

Answer (score 1):

The recursive function is calculating the [factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial) of `n`.
The function will call itself until it reaches a base case.
You have one base case: when `n` is `1` then return 1.

If you call it with say `5` then it works as follows:

```
recur(5) =>  
5 * recur(4) =>  
5 * 4 * recur(3) =>  
5 * 4 * 3 * recur(2) =>  
5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * recur(1) =>  
5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 =>  
120
```

So the result will be 120 for `n=5`.